# Jquery countdown serverSync for 15 secs timer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, timer, jquery-countdown

I have website with some objects. Each object has timer set on 15 seconds. I use jQuery countdown with cookies to provide saving of remaining time, but I think it's bad idea because I need cookie for each object.

Can I use jQuery countdown with serverSync to provide this functional? I think I need function for serverSync which sends request to server each second and updates remaining time on that, but it means if I will have 50 objects with timers I will send 50 requests to server on second! What can I do to avoid server's crash? Or it will be ok?

Comment: You only need to get the server time once then adjust the page timers accordingly.

Comment: Ok. But I can't understand how can I store remaining time when page reload using this way?